# Remove white space at the end of a line above a list environment

Tags: align, hfill

Why is there a space on the right side of 'A', but no space on the right side of 'B'? How can I remove the space on the right side of 'A' so it is in line with 'B'?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{list1}{
  \begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0.03in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} 
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\section{\sc\noindent Education}
\begin{list1}
    \item[] {\bf Ph.D.  \hfill A}
    \begin{list1}
        \item[-] Thesis: 
    \end{list1}
    \item[] {\bf BEcon.  \hfill B}
\end{list1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! You should be aware that the two-letter font selection commands have been deprecated for about 30 years.

Comment: every `list1` adds 4 spaces, use `%` to hide ends of lines

Comment: you have not defined `\ding` so using `\item` without `[]` will give an error

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you! problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Protect the endlines with `%`.

However, it's simpler with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newlist{list1}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[list1]{nosep,leftmargin=0.17in}
\setlist[list1,1]{label=\ding{113}}
\setlist[list1,2]{label=--}

\begin{document}

\section{\sc\noindent Education}
\begin{list1}
    \item \textbf{Ph.D.}\hfill\textbf{A}
    \begin{list1}
        \item Thesis: 
    \end{list1}
    \item \textbf{BEcon.}\hfill \textbf{B}
\end{list1}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\bf`, `\sc` and the other two-letter font selection commands have been obsolete for about 30 years.

You need `pifont` for `\ding`.

[image]